# Array to HTML table with few adjustments

Tags: php

I would like to create a html table from the following array.
But this table is a bit complicated to make, because the header should contain the different sizes (34 - 41) and the location should be only displayed once per line. Also the first [0] => 124 shouldn't be displayed, like this:

```
                sizes
 loc   34 - 35 - 38 - 39 - 40 - 41
 124    1    1    2    2    1    1
 424    1    1    0    0    0    0
 1512   1    1    0    0    0    0
 1612   0    0    1    1    2    2
 1711   0    0    1    1    1    1
```

In my search for the solution, I've found this code, but this shows everything on two lines.

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '  <th colspan="1">'.$key.'</th>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<th colspan="1">No subcat</th>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
//Data
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
```

The array

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [Loc] => 124
             [0] => 124
             [34] => 1
             [35] => 1
             [38] => 2
             [39] => 2
             [40] => 1
             [41] => 1
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [Loc] => 424
             [0] => 424
             [34] => 1
             [35] => 1
             [38] => 0
             [39] => 0
             [40] => 0
             [41] => 0
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [Loc] => 1512
             [0] => 1512
             [34] => 1
             [35] => 1
             [38] => 0
             [39] => 0
             [40] => 0
             [41] => 0
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [Loc] => 1612
             [0] => 1612
             [34] => 0
             [35] => 0
             [38] => 1
             [39] => 1
             [40] => 2
             [41] => 2
         )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [Loc] => 1711
             [0] => 1711
             [34] => 0
             [35] => 0
             [38] => 1
             [39] => 1
             [40] => 1
             [41] => 1
         )

 )
```

Comment: _“but this shows everything on two lines”_ - well that’s because of where the TR elements are opened and closed ... That should happen _inside_ the outer loop, not outside both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must display only the first line in the first `foreach`. (You showed all the lines).

You must `break;` after one `foreach`

Then, display each data from the second `foreach` on a single line via

```
<tr>
```

(You were showing all the lines in one    `tr`)

Also, you do not have to display the values with key "0"

Here is the corrected code

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            if($key!='0')echo '  <th colspan="1">'.$key.'</th>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<th colspan="1">No subcat</th>';
    }
    break;
}
echo '</tr>';
//Data
foreach( $result as $key => $value )
{
echo '<tr>';
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            if($key!='0')echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
echo '</tr>';
}
```